# I have three microservices which are made in node Now I want to make a one apigateway for these services using nest js with kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, microservices, nest

**How to connect these three microservices to api gateway. And this API gateway must be in nestjs with kafka server. So how can i connect apigateway and microservices.**

I am not getting how to connect this services which are made in node and api gateway in nest.

The services are:

> 1-ms-authentication
> 2-ms-notification
> 3-ms-application

There is one API gateway which is **nest-kafka-api-gateway**.

Is it possible to connect api gateway in nest and this applications are in node??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Nestjs "Hybrid application" as gateway. [NestJS Hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#hybrid-application)

Comment: Is it possible to use Kafka in the hybrid application?

Comment: Yes, it is! [NestJS Microservice Kafka](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka)